# MVC.Net Controller path with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[Route("add/user/{name}&{state}&{zipcode}&{indeFlag}&{email}")]     
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUser(
                 string name,
                 string state,
                 string zipcode,
                 Boolean indeFlag,
                 string email)
{
}
```

How to define Route of the controller method in the example above to that I can pass correct data to the method?

Please help.

Comment: what you wanna do in this case, by this you wanna add user by typing a url only. don't have a specific page for that.

Comment: Is it a Post operation you are trying ?

Comment: As Ravi says, this looks like it should be a post, so you should decorate it with a [HttpPost] attribute.
I see you're using & which makes it look like you're trying to do this via a GET.
It would be more typical, for you to POST those values in the body of the request, as json.
Then your route would not contain those parameters, it would just be add/user, which is easier to work with.

Comment: I'm actually trying to add a new user manually by directly calling that controller method via url and passing parameters in the url. This url can be accessed by admins only. A quick way to add an user.

Comment: Yes @Viplock. I want to add user by typing a url only for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass each parameter like this :

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{

     // < MVC 6 :

     [Route("add")] 
     [HttpPost]    
     public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
                 string name,
                 string state,
                 string zipcode,
                 bool indeFlag,
                 string email)
     {
         // Your code here
     }

     // If you want call this in a simple get query
     [Route("quickadd")] 
     [HttpGet]    
     public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
                 string name,
                 string state,
                 string zipcode,
                 bool indeFlag,
                 string email)
     {
         // Your code here
     }

     // MVC 6 :

     [Route("add")] 
     [HttpPost]    
     public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
                 [FromForm]string name,
                 [FromForm]string state,
                 [FromForm]string zipcode,
                 [FromForm]bool indeFlag,
                 [FromForm]string email)
     {
         // Your code here
     }

     // If you want call this in a simple get query
     [Route("quickadd")] 
     [HttpGet]    
     public async Task<IActionResult> QuickAdd(
                 [FromQuery]string name,
                 [FromQuery]string state,
                 [FromQuery]string zipcode,
                 [FromQuery]bool indeFlag,
                 [FromQuery]string email)
     {
         // Your code here
     }

}
```

The url will be '/user/add' with data in form.

Other solution, better by the way, is to use a view model class, like this :

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
{

     [Route("add")] 
     [HttpPost]    
     public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
                 AddViewModel model)
     {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
              // Put your code to create user here
         }
         else
         {
              // Put your code for error here
         }
     }

}
```

A view model allows you to use Data Annotation to do some checks, like required fields, or format checks.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class AddViewModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
     [Display(Name = "Username")]
     [DataType(DataType.Text)]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string State{ get; set; }

     [Required]
     [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
     public string Email{ get; set; }

     [Required]
     [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
     public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }

     public AddViewModel()
     {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrien for the detailed response.I'm actually trying to add a new user manually by directly calling that controller method via url and passing parameters in the url. This url can be accessed by admins only. A quick way to add an user.

Comment: Oh. So you can do this : [Route("quickadd")] 
     [HttpGet]    
     public async Task<IActionResult> QuickAdd(
                 [FromQuery]string name,
                 [FromQuery]string state,
                 [FromQuery]string zipcode,
                 [FromQuery]bool indeFlag,
                 [FromQuery]string email)
     {
         // Your code here
     }

Comment: You can call the url like /user/quickadd?name=jkdjkds&state=kjsdjkd etc in a simple get query ;)